# REST public POST giving 403 forbidden nginx

Tags: ajax, rest-api, endpoints

I have created public rest endpoint with POST method and when I try ajax or use insomnia always response with 403 forbidden nginx. Why isn't this working and how could I resolve my problem?

Route:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'registerContactPOST');

function registerContactPOST(){
    register_rest_route('fb/v1', 'contact',
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'contactPOST',
            'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
        )
    );
}

function contactPOST($requestData){
    return 'ok';
}
```

Client ajax:

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax( {
        url: '/wp-json/fb/v1/contact',
        method: 'POST',
        data:{
            'xyz' : 'xyz'
        }
    } ).done( function ( response ) {
        console.log( response );
    } );
</script>
```

In xampp localhost it works fine but not with remote server.

Comment: Welcome to wpse! your url should be absolute, not relative

Comment: @Buttered_Toast its not about path because test in insomnia with post method still gives 403. But ok, I will change to absolute

Answer (score 0):

After searching the internet looking for an answer, I contact my hosting provider. They had blocked every non-standard gateway for security purpose. Now it's resolved.